# Linear independence of set with added vector

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space and $ v_1,\dots,v_k \in V$ be a set of linearly independent vectors.

Proof that if $w \in V $ and $ v_1+w,\dots,v_k+w $  linearly dependent, then $ w \in span\{v_1,\dots,v_k\} $.

**My solution:**

Suppose

$a_1(v_1+w) + \dots + a_k(v_k+w) = 0$

*Because of the linear dependence of $v_1+w,\dots, v_k+w$ there is atleast one $a_i \neq 0 (i=1,\dots,k)$*

Then

$a_1v_1+\dots+a_kv_k +xw= 0$ with $x=(a_1+\dots+a_k)$.

Because $v_1, \dots, v_k$ is linearly independent $a_1v_1+\dots+a_kv_k = 0$ has only $a_1=\dots=a_k=0$ as a solution and therefore $x \neq 0$.

So $ w = -\frac{a_1}{x} v_1-\dots-\frac{a_n}{x} v_n$ and $w \in span\{v_1,\dots,v_k\}$.

Is this correct?

Comment: Sorry I read improperly your question. The statement holds but the proof is false. You didn't use the fact that $v_1+w,...,v_k+w$ are linearly dependent (or at least didn't make it clear how you used it to deduce that $x\not = 0$).

Comment: My reasoning why $x \neq0 $ is because of the linearly dependence of $v_1+w, \dots, v_k+w$

Comment: I understand that. But you need to add two lines, first that you choose $a_1,...,a_k$ where at least one of them is none  zero and another line that if by contradiction $x=0$ then $a_1v_1+...+a_kv_k=0$ and so $a_1=...=a_k=0$.

Comment: That is invalid reasoning.  You can have linearly dependent vectors $v_1+w,\cdots,v_k+w$ with $a_1(v_1+w)+\cdots+a_k(v_k+w)=0$ and $a_1+\cdots+a_k=0$.  For example let $k=2$, $v_1=v_2$, $w=0$, $a_1=1$, $a_2=-1$.

Comment: Your $v_1$ and $v_2$ are linearly dependent

Comment: That's right.  See, it's about linear independence of the $v_i$'s, not about linear dependence of the $(v_i+w)$'s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is sort of correct, but there is an ambiguity here:  "$a_1v_1+\cdots+a_kv_k=0$ has only $a_1=\cdots=a_k=0$ as a solution and therefore $x\neq 0$."
That is true but it is unclear if you really understand why.

*Proof.*  Let $a_1,\cdots,a_k\in\mathbb{F}$, not all zero, such that
$$0=\sum_{i=1}^ka_i(v_i+w).$$
It cannot be that $x:=a_1+\cdots+a_k=0$, otherwise we would have
$$0=\sum_{i=1}^ka_i(v_i+w)=\sum_{i=1}^ka_iv_i,$$
contradicting linear independence of $\{v_i\}_{i=1}^k$.  Thus
$$0=\sum_{i=1}^ka_i(v_i+w)=xw+\sum_{i=1}^ka_iv_i,$$
and hence
$$w=-\frac{1}{x}\sum_{i=1}^ka_iv_i\in\text{span}\{v_i\}_{i=1}^k.\;\;\square$$